# What alternatives are there to a retaining wall?

Tags: retaining-wall

The retaining wall surrounding my foundation on the street side of my residence has fallen and has been partially removed. The rest of it will need to come down, and I'm trying to find another option that's in my budget.

Someone suggested to get the soil leveled a little and plant sod. It's a slope-like area with my house sitting about 8ft away from where the wall was and close to the sidewalk that people walk on. Would it be safe to do that? I don't want to ruin the foundation to my house.

Comment: Can you add an image or two to provide some context?  Also, maybe a sketch of the house footprint showing the location of the wall and describing the surrounding grade?  Why was the wall there?

Comment: How tall was this retaining wall?  That's going to change your options quite a bit.

Comment: oh darn!  ... i just cannot see your house from here. ... so i have no idea what you are talking about .... ask your neighbours, they will know what you are talking about

Comment: Landscaping is [specifically off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help) here. You might try http://gardening.stackexchange.com.

Comment: What kind of foundation do you have?

Answer (score 2):

You really have two primary options--slope or no (minimal) slope.

With the no-slope option you need either a single retaining wall or multiple tiers of landscaping. You could use small boulders to create two or three individual levels and fill between with gardens of various sorts.

With the sloped option you need to prevent erosion, so sod or a stable covering is needed. Crushed rock or paving stones might work.

Answer (score 0):

The most solid fix I think would be a split face cinderblock retaining wall.  You have to dig a footer, add rebar, get the buggys and pour in the footer.  Next start building up your motor and cinder block split face wall.  Maybe 24" tall (shouldn't need a permit) which means 3 blocks high.  Once everything is mortored in place, add galvanized fence posts (if you want/need) right into the blocks.  With the rebars sticking straight up (don't forget to cap them if left open overnight) get another buggy and pour concrete to fill all the cinderblocks.  That retaining wall will stop a truck.

Comment: I prefer a wall constructed of the engineered concrete blocks by Keystone or Versa-Lok. These are heavy blocks which are pinned with fibreglass epoxy pegs, but no mortar. They can shift without cracking, and water can seep through the joints.

Comment: The question asks specifically for alternatives to a wall.